# How Can I Modify Text in a Safari Contextmenu Extension

Tags: javascript, safari, contextmenu

I'm brand new to javascript and writing extensions so I need your help.

I'm trying to create a Safari context menu item which will allow the user to modify text that he has entered when he selects some or all of the text in the input window (like the one I'm asking this question in). 

I have it partially working in that my extension shows up in the context menu, and clicking it calls my `global.html` file which in turn calls my End Script, `inject.js`, file which looks like this:

```
function handleMessage(event) {
  var range = window.getSelection();//.getRangeAt(0);
   console.log("range:"+range);
  var selectionParentText = range.startContainer.textContent;
  range.startContainer.textContent = selectionParentText.substring(0,range.startOffset) + "[b]" + range.toString() + "[/b]" + selectionParentText.substring(range.endOffset,selectionParentText.length);
}

safari.self.addEventListener("message", handleMessage, false);
```

The log shows the value of the text I select but the 4th line generates a `TypeError: Result of expression 'range.startContainer' [undefined] is not an object.` error. What is the proper way to modify the selected text?

Answer (score 0):

```
function handleMessage(event) 
{
  var e = document.activeElement;
  if (e.tagName = "textarea")
  {
    var selLen = e.selectionEnd - e.selectionStart;
    e.value = e.value.substr(0, e.selectionStart) + "[b]" + e.value.substr(e.selectionStart, selLen) + "[/b]" + e.value.substr(e.selectionEnd, e.value.length);
  }
}

safari.self.addEventListener("message", handleMessage, false);
```